# How to send ndarray response from flask server to python client?

Tags: json, flask, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to send ndarray (predictionsIm) of shape (1536,1536,3) from flask server to the python client.
I read around for converting predictionsIm (ndarray) to list and then return the json, so I did as below:

```
return {'predictions' : predictionsIm.tolist()}
```

but I don't know how to handle it on client slide, can someone help in this approach?

or suggest a better approach?

Following is my request.py:

```
import requests
sample_input = "/mnt/d/work/MASKRCNN/data_example/img0001.png"
resp = requests.post("http://localhost:5000/predict",
                     files={"file": open(sample_input,'rb')})

print(resp.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot the json step

```
return jsonify({'predictions' : predictionsIm.tolist()})
```