# Python 3.7 TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument: 'input'

Tags: python, python-server-pages

I have already finished my function, but when I run the webserver I get the following error:

[TypeError : index() missing 1 required positional argument:'input'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tczt6.png)

This is my code:

```
from sklearn import tree
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index(input):
    input = [[1,1,2,3,3,1,1,2]]

    data = pd.read_csv('datawadek.csv')
    y = data.KELAS
    x = data.drop('KELAS', axis = 1)

    cart = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

    cart = cart.fit(x,y)

    return cart.predict(input)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am very new to python programming. Please help me with any suggestions or solutions.

Have a nice day

Comment: Don’t name a variable `input`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want to pass input as a parameter in flask. You cannot define the input as parameters to your flask's endpoint function. Instead, you should read the parameters inside the said function with `request.args.get` like this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    input = request.args.get('input')
    if input is None:
        input = [[1,1,2,3,3,1,1,2]]
```

From [python docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.request):

> The `request` object is automatically reachable from all flask api's
>   and it contains all the data that you are passing through the api. To
>   access incoming request data, you can use the global request object.
>   Flask parses incoming request data for you and gives you access to it
>   through that global object. Internally Flask makes sure that you
>   always get the correct data for the active thread if you are in a
>   multithreaded environment.

EDIT:

In the comments we had a similar example with path parameter:

```
@app.route('/<input>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index(input):
```

the final result will be identical to my initial answer above, but it less practical from design standpoint. You would be using a post method to pass an array of data and in this case, the data should come inside a request.

Another reason to not do it is that you should also **always** avoid passing an array as a path parameter unless

Comment: You can pass name as a param to flask view only if there is regex in app.route.

    `@app.route('/<input:input>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

     def index(input):`

Comment: @RahulRaut err i didnt understand it, so i must change app = Flask(__name__) to app = Flask (__param__) ? and change the app.route code?

Comment: @DewadekKrisna I updated my answer to address this question

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas i already update my code as u suggest but after run on it and go to web but i got 404 not found in web and in cmd i got (typeerror :The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a ndarray) did i doing something wrong?
i'm so sry im still new on these thing

Comment: The error says that `return cart.predict(input)` the result of this predict is a numpy array. Numpy array is not a valid flask return type. You should thus cast this result to list as in `return cart.predict(input).tolist()`. See: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html

Comment: i already add it but it still same just change "but it was a list" code,

Comment: My bad, apparently you need to return the response in json format. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58433450/how-to-send-ndarray-response-from-flask-server-to-python-client

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas aah but can u at least give the right code for me? oh fyi this server is planned for and android apps client

Comment: The answer was given in the question that I have linked you~ `return jsonify({'predictions' : predictionsIm.tolist()})`

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas so i must change return cart.predict(input) into return jsonify({'predictions' : predictionsIm.tolist()}) ?

Comment: should be `jsonify({'predictions' : cart.predict(input).tolist()})`

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas aah thank you buddy, no error these time in cmd (still 404 not found in web, maybe cause it server )